# HTML/PHP post methode

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server

I have input type "text" created from php echo, how can I get value of this input, I can only get value of input created in html with `$_post[name];` but input created with php I can't please help me ....

```
 <?php 
    echo "<form name='flogin' action='javascript:addclt()' onsubmit='return validateF()' method='poste' accept-charset='UTF-8'><div class='login'>";
    echo "<P class='horz'>CODE  <input type='text' placeholder='K1047' nom='ccode'></P>";
 ?>
```

this what i get like error :

> Notice: Undefined index: ccode in C:\P..............

I use :

```
<? php 
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (code) VALUES ('$_POST[ccode]')";
?>
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to echo all HTML. You can just open and close PHP tags whereever you want. Your first snippet doesn't even have to have any PHP snippet at all.

Comment: Also note that it's bad practice to embed the $_POST value like that. See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for examples of the right (safe!) way to do it.

Comment: sorry, but i use tow (02) deffirent files; I use echo because i create input in other html file, i use javascript to call this php section

Comment: You can also include PHP files without PHP tags into other PHP files. A valid plain HTML file is also a valid PHP file. You don't *have* to change it, of course, but HTML is much more readable if it isn't inside a PHP string, so it's just well meant advice.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
<input type='text' placeholder='K1047' nom='ccode'>
```

Change "nom" with "name" - syntax error.

```
<input type='text' placeholder='K1047' name='ccode'>
```